# Run command at startup on Ubuntu server 17

Tags: networking, server, startup

I am setting up a ubuntu cluster in PXE. So I need to know the IPs of all nodes to use distcc or others programs like OpenMPI. The command which I need to run is

```
ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p' >> /home/owner/ips
```

I tried with crontab, if using the *touch* command the file is created, but nothing in the *ips* file, also tried *upstart* and *systemd*, including *init.d* methods. But they do not works with this command which need to be run at the final runlevel.

Comment: Make your life easy and configure static IP address leases in your DHCP server and run a DNS server, so you can use hostnames for your job. `dnsmasq` is pretty easy to set up for such a task.

Comment: I am already running a DHCP server. But like it is not a static network, and I cannot know in advance the MAC addresses of these nodes... And the DNS server is also already working and given by default by DHCP. Note that nodes cannot access the main server unless for TFTP or NFS.